# see what type is a dynamic variable c#

Tags: c#, dynamic

how can I test if a dynamic variable is a double for example?

I need to do something like:

```
void someMethod(dynamic var1)
{
  if(var1.isDouble)
  {...
  }else if(var1 is int)
  // do something else....


}
```

Comment: You might want to think about whether you can just use `object` instead of `dynamic`. You can still do `if (var1 is double)` with that. You don’t need `dynamic` unless you really need dynamic dispatch at runtime, which your example doesn’t use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That approach is fine (i.e. `var1 is double`), though that's usually not what `dynamic` is meant to accomplish. More often, you should `dynamic` when you *do* know what the type will be, but it's difficult or impossible to show that at compile-time (e.g. a COM interop scenario, a `ViewBag` in MVC, etc.) You could just use `object` if you want to pass a variable of unknown type. Otherwise, the run-time will do the type analysis for you during execution, which can be a big performance hit if that's not what you need.

In general, there could be scenarios where you'd want to use `dynamic` as a catch-all container, but this doesn't appear to be one of them. In this case, why not have a number of method overloads that each take the desired type:

```
void someMethod(double d) { ... }
void someMethod(int i) { ... }
```

Comment: I'd like to clarify in regards to "catch all container". You should think of dynamic == object in regards to method signatures. `dynamic` only does it's work at invocation, `dynamic` as an argument type in the signature really is only useful to reduce casting inside your method when you are wanting to use dynamic invocation there.  If you have a `someMethod(dynamic d)` in addition to the int & double overloads and you call `someMethod((dynamic)5)` the int overload will be called rather than dynamic because casting to dynamic in this case means use the runtime type to resolve the overload.

Answer (score 4):

This scenario has nothing to do with `dynamic` keyword as [explained by dlev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986938/see-what-type-is-a-dynamic-variable-c/6986966#6986966).

Did you mean:

```
void someMethod(object o)
{
    if (o is double) {
        double d = (double)o;
        // do something with d
    } else if (o is int) {
        int i = (int)o;
        // do something with i
    }
}
```

Either way, this is generally a bad practice unless absolutely needed.
**What are you trying to accomplish?**

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this work:

```
if(var1 is Double)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the type is *implicitly convertible* to double, with the `is` keyword:

```
if (var1 is double)
```

Comment: Uhm? Implicitly convertible? No, sir, you got your terms mixed up :)